# How can I see all versions of a package that are available in the archive?

Tags: package-management, apt, archive

Is there a way I can see all the versions that are in the archives that I have configured in **sources.list**. I can see the last version of each archive with`apt-get policy`, but how can I see them all?

Is there any way that this can also include *PPA* and anything in *sources.list.d*?

Answer (score 422, accepted):

As far as I understand your requirements, the madison option for apt-cache does what you want:

> madison /[ pkg(s) ]
>   apt-cache's madison command attempts to mimic the output format and a subset of the functionality of the Debian archive management tool, madison. It displays available versions of a package in a tabular format. Unlike the original madison, it can only display information for the architecture for which APT has retrieved package lists (APT::Architecture).

On my computer:

```
$ apt-cache madison f-spot
    f-spot | 0.7.2-1~ppa~lucid0 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/f-spot/f-spot-ppa/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
    f-spot | 0.6.1.5-2ubuntu7 | http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Packages
    f-spot | 0.6.1.5-2ubuntu6 | http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Packages
    f-spot | 0.6.1.5-2ubuntu6 | http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid/main Sources
    f-spot | 0.6.1.5-2ubuntu7 | http://ro.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ lucid-updates/main Sources
```

I hope this is what you need. It also includes the ppas.

Comment: why called madison?

Comment: The command `apt list -a <package name>` is the equivalent of madison.

Comment: Here's why it's called _madison_ https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/276037/why-apt-madison/276040#276040

Answer (score 249):

The command

```
apt list -a <package name>
```

is the equivalent of madison.

Comment: Can second, I like the output this command produces. I just want to know the version numbers available to me, I don't need all the additional information and warnings and messaging.

Answer (score 68):

The `rmadison` program from the `devscripts` package will remotely query the Ubuntu archive and give you the status of a package in all supported releases, not only those you have locally insatlled. This is slightly more than what you want, but should get the job done easily.

Example:

```
lfaraone@stone:~$ rmadison sudo
      sudo | 1.6.8p12-1ubuntu6 |        dapper | source, amd64, i386, powerpc
      sudo | 1.6.8p12-1ubuntu6.3 | dapper-security | source, amd64, i386, powerpc
      sudo | 1.6.8p12-1ubuntu6.3 | dapper-updates | source, amd64, i386, powerpc
      sudo | 1.6.9p10-1ubuntu3 |         hardy | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.6.9p10-1ubuntu3.8 | hardy-security | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.6.9p10-1ubuntu3.8 | hardy-updates | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.6.9p17-1ubuntu3 |        jaunty | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.6.9p17-1ubuntu3.3 | jaunty-security | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.6.9p17-1ubuntu3.3 | jaunty-updates | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.0-1ubuntu2 |        karmic | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.0-1ubuntu2.4 | karmic-security | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.0-1ubuntu2.4 | karmic-updates | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.2p1-1ubuntu5 |         lucid | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.2p1-1ubuntu5.1 | lucid-security | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.2p1-1ubuntu5.1 | lucid-updates | source, amd64, i386
      sudo | 1.7.2p7-1ubuntu1 |      maverick | source, amd64, i386
```

before you can use `rmadison` you must install the `devscripts` package:

```
sudo apt-get install devscripts
```

Comment: This only shows the main archives, but not the ppas

Comment: Very nice!  But it also doesn't show unsupported packages, which are still available at http://old-releases.ubuntu.com/  I've asked about that at [Information on package versions from old releases? - Ask Ubuntu - Stack Exchange](http://askubuntu.com/questions/38071/information-on-package-versions-from-old-releases)

Comment: `rmadison ffmpeg` currently shows 14 lines of results, including "7:4.1.3-0ubuntu1", which is what I'm interested in ( https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/ffmpeg/7:4.1.3-0ubuntu1 ) But then `sudo apt install ffmpeg=7:4.1.3-0ubuntu1` results in: "Reading package lists... Done Building dependency tree Reading state information... Done E: Version '7:4.1.3-0ubuntu1' for 'ffmpeg' was not found"

Answer (score 39):

I don't know how (or why) you said `apt-cache policy` doesn't show all versions! I'm using this for several years now and It always showed all versions including the priority number.

#### Output of `apt-cache policy nautilus`

```
nautilus:
  Installed: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Candidate: 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1
  Version table:
 *** 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 500
        500 file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/xenial1  Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie-remix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 500
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 500
        500 file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/xenial1  Packages
        500 http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
     1:3.14.2-0ubuntu13 500
        500 file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/wily  Packages
```

#### Output of `apt-cache madison nautilus`

```
  nautilus | 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 | file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/xenial1  Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/budgie-remix/ppa/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.18.5-0ubuntu1~xenial1 | http://ppa.launchpad.net/gnome3-team/gnome3/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu5 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 | file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/xenial1  Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.18.4.is.3.14.3-0ubuntu4 | http://us.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 Packages
  nautilus | 1:3.14.2-0ubuntu13 | file:/media/Linux/apt-repo/wily  Packages
```

Only difference is that `madison` took some more time than `policy` and shorter version. But, `policy` is more useful to see which version get installed, which version is next candidate to be installed.

That's why I'd suggest always using `apt-cache policy <package-name>` instead.

*Note about output:* I have some local repository setup and both of the command shows those as well.

*Note 2* Newer apt comes with policy integrated into them. So, you can use `apt` instead of `apt-cache` directly.

Answer (score 1):

Neither rmadison nor apt-cache policy will show all packages available. This is due to them relying on the package manifest list contained within each repo. However, rmadison is slightly better because it will show you packages available from all repositories you have added to your system instead of the top weighted ones like apt-cache policy does.

If you really want to see, browse to the repository in question in your web browser and go to the correct path (something like this: https://repo.zabbix.com/zabbix/6.3/ubuntu/pool/main/z/zabbix/).

You'll then see all the debs there you could potentially install for a particular version even before the vendor updates the manifest for apt to grab the "newest" release.

I'm sure this could also be done with a simple for loop and curl in a bash script.

Comment: This solution depends on the apt repository's HTTP server having directory indexing available. For repositories hosted on Amazon S3, for instance, that won't be the case.

Regardless, if the apt repository's manifest doesn't list a package, that package isn't "in" the repository, and if you download and install it directly then things like "apt-get upgrade" may well get confused in future.