# Dependency problem with mysql-server-core-5.5

Tags: mysql

When I start the Ubuntu software centre, it says I cannot do anything until the package catalog is repaired. However, repairing fails.

I ran `sudo apt-get -f install` and found the problem to be:

```
mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2.
```

So, the question is, how do I install that version and resolve the dependency problem?

Comment: Did you install anything from source?

Comment: I had this problem, but really what was needed was a "purge" (from this thread: http://askubuntu.com/questions/292865/upgrade-mysql-server-issue)

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`

Answer (score 3):

Since I didn't actually need MySQL server anymore I solved this by uninstalling programs with unresolved dependencies one by one.

First I had a similar error:

```
mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1)
  but 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is to be installed
```

I uninstalled `mysql-server-core-5.5` using `dpkg`:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove mysql-server-core-5.5
```

The another error arised:

```
mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.2)
  but it is not going to be installed
```

Uninstall `mysql-server-5.5` this time:

```
$ sudo dpkg --remove mysql-server-5.5
```

One step higher in the hierarchy:

```
mysql-server : Depends: mysql-server-5.5 but it is not going to be installed
```

Uninstall `mysql-server`:

```
sudo dpkg --remove mysql-server
```

Seems to work now.

Answer (score 2):

First make sure your package sources are correct. Then run a

`sudo apt-get update

sudo apt-get -f install`

just to make sure. If that still doesn't work then continue on.

Remove the offending package

`sudo dpkg --remove 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2`

folowed by

`sudo apt-get -f install`

This should remove MySQL completely (including the meta packages you stated).

You can then re-install with:

`sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5`

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem with mysql-server-core-5.5 version 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

> mysql-server-5.5 depende de mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.24-0ubuntu0.12.04.1); 
>   sin embargo:
>   La versión de `mysql-server-core-5.5' en el sistema es 5.5.29-0ubuntu0.12.04.1

I solved it with this commands:

1. Backup de database(s)
2. Check all version avaible of mysql-server for you linux distribution. [sudo apt-cache madison mysql-server-5.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447/how-can-i-see-all-versions-of-a-package-that-are-available-in-the-archive).
3. Remove the packages of mysql-server. `sudo apt-get remove mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5`.
4. Install a old version (see the second point for select one). And run the command: `sudo apt-get install mysql-server-5.5=5.5.22-0ubuntu1 mysql-server-core-5.5=5.5.22-0ubuntu1`