# Upgrade MySQL server issue

Tags: apt, mysql

I failed to upgrade MySQL server. Here's what I tried:

I first issue this command to update the package list:

```
sudo apt-get update
```

Then, upgrade by:

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

It shows the following error:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 mysql-server-5.5 : Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2) but 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1 is installed
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

Apparently a newer version is installed (but why? I didn't install manually). Okay, As it suggests, I issue the command to attempt fixing:

```
sudo apt-get -f install
```

Here is the output:

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Correcting dependencies... Done
The following extra packages will be installed:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
Suggested packages:
  tinyca mailx
The following packages will be upgraded:
  mysql-server mysql-server-5.5
2 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 3 not upgraded.
2 not fully installed or removed.
Need to get 0 B/8889 kB of archives.
After this operation, 64.5 kB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue [Y/n]? Y
perl: warning: Setting locale failed.
perl: warning: Please check that your locale settings:
    LANGUAGE = (unset),
    LC_ALL = (unset),
    LC_CTYPE = "UTF-8",
    LANG = "en_HK.UTF-8"
    are supported and installed on your system.
perl: warning: Falling back to the standard locale ("C").
locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server-5.5:
 mysql-server-5.5 depends on mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.2); however:
  Version of mysql-server-core-5.5 on system is 5.5.31-0ubuntu0.12.04.1.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server-5.5 (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          dpkg: dependency problems prevent configuration of mysql-server:
 mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
  Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
dpkg: error processing mysql-server (--configure):
 dependency problems - leaving unconfigured
No apport report written because the error message indicates its a followup error from a previous failure.
                          Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Then I try to use another command that some people suggest in the Internet:

```
sudo apt-get -f upgrade
```

Same output is produced. Apart from re-installing MySQL server, what else can I do ?

using Ubuntu server 12.04 LTS

Comment: no idea if it will work, but did you try dist-upgrade instead of upgrade?

Comment: That saved my day! Clear steps.

http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/mysql-job-failed-to-start-unable-to-set-root-password-cant-find-file-mysql/

Comment: Similar question: http://askubuntu.com/questions/697805/package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet

Answer (score 29, accepted):

That happened to me but it was that, after doing a `sudo apt-get update` it somehow did not get the newest version of the `mysql-server`, only of the `mysql-server-core`. I would first suggest to do another `sudo apt-get update` and then proceed on installing the package

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If that does not work then do a reinstall:

```
sudo apt-get install --reinstall mysql-server
```

And if that does not work, then simply `purge` the package `mysql-server-core` package, then install `mysql-server` again.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql-server-core mysql-server-core-5.5

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

And if that does not work then go crazy on it with:

```
sudo apt-get clean

sudo apt-get autoclean

sudo apt-get purge mysql-server*

sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

As a last resort, I would purge, reboot, install.

Comment: Thanks, but will it delete the database schema during re-install ?

Comment: No it won't. Even purging will not touch your already created database schemes. It will however overkill whatever problem you are having.

Comment: Note: purge will ask for a new mysql root password

Comment: in my case, after all those steps. "Unable to set password for mysql "root" user ". and then fails with:   Errors were encountered while processing:
 mysql-server-5.5
 mysql-server
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)

Comment: @ses did you search askubuntu for that error. I mean for that "Unable to set password for mysql" error. I got several that already have the answer I was going to say.

Comment: That helped me.
http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/mysql-job-failed-to-start-unable-to-set-root-password-cant-find-file-mysql/

Comment: You are on some next level Luis, thanks for this (had to go crazy too)

Comment: great post, love it. very much helpful.

Comment: Similar problem after an upgrade of Ubuntu 18.04 to 20.04. Had to do the `go crazy` method but the difference on my system was that `mysql-server-5.7*` was still lingering. So my `go crazy` was more radical and involved `apt-get purge mysql`

Comment: The [randomhacks.co.uk](/...https://www.randomhacks.co.uk/mysql-job-failed-to-start-unable-to-set-root-password-cant-find-file-mysql/) solution in the comment by @ses resolved my issue too. I was getting multiple `dpkg: too many errors` messages using `apt-get` but purging from `dpkg` worked first time.