# Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet

Tags: apt, mysql

**Question**

I am installing a LEMP stack on a fresh minimal install of Ubuntu 14.04 LTS.

When I tried to install MySql

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

it returned an error with the following explanation:

```
mysql-server depends on mysql-server-5.5; however:
Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet.
```

How do I solve this problem?

**What I have read**

This question is very similar to [Upgrade MySQL server issue](https://askubuntu.com/questions/292865/upgrade-mysql-server-issue), however, that question was (incorrectly, I believe) marked as a duplicate of [this question](https://askubuntu.com/questions/125686/failed-to-spawn-mysql-main-process-unable-to-execute-no-such-file-or-director). None of the answers to these two questions solved my problem.

I have also seen [E: Mysql-server-5.5 Installation Error](https://askubuntu.com/questions/384234/e-mysql-server-5-5-installation-error). This question was closed for being unreproducible. However, I can reproduce my problem every time I try to install mysql server on a fresh minimal installation of Ubuntu 14.04 (the key word being minimal).

**Purpose of this question**

I finally solved my problem, but I could not add an answer to any of the questions I linked to above, so I am creating a new question here so that I can answer it myself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The main problem is that the minimal Ubuntu install does not have everything that you need.

The post [Package mysql-server-5.5 is not configured yet](https://web.archive.org/web/20150502134659/http://tutewall.com/package-mysql-server-5-5-is-not-configured-yet) provides the solution to your problem. I suggest you read that. However, I will provide a brief summary below.

Clean out the old mysql installation.

```
sudo apt-get purge mysql*
sudo apt-get autoremove
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

Upgrade the things that are missing in the minimal Ubuntu installation.

```
sudo apt-get dist-upgrade
```

Install MySql as normal:

```
sudo apt-get install mysql-server
```

If that still doesn't work you can do

```
 sudo apt-get install mysql-server --fix-missing --fix-broken
```