# How to solve mysql dependency problem

Tags: apt, mysql

Hi I ran the following command

```
sudo apt-get upgrade
```

However I'm getting the following

```
You might want to run 'apt-get -f install' to correct these.
The following packages have unmet dependencies:  mysql-server-5.5 :
Depends: mysql-server-core-5.5 (= 5.5.28-0ubuntu0.12.04.3) but 5.5.35-0ubuntu0.12.04.2 is installed 
E: Unmet dependencies. Try using -f.
```

I came across the following [Dependency problem with mysql-server-core-5.5](https://askubuntu.com/questions/218418/dependency-problem-with-mysql-server-core-5-5) but not sure how I should go about applying it to my situation.

Any help would be appreciated

Comment: [This answer](http://askubuntu.com/a/218434/45659) should work for you, failing which, [try this](http://askubuntu.com/a/255927/45659), changing the version numbers as appropriate. I am voting to close this question as a duplicate.

Comment: which version number do I change? and to what do I change it?

Comment: In the command `apt-get install mysql-server-5.5=<version> mysql-server-core-5.5=<version>`, the version number should match what you see from the apt-cache madison output.

Comment: What is the output of `apt-cache policy mysql-server-5.5 mysql-server-core-5.5` and `cat /etc/apt/sources.list{,.d/*.list}`.

Comment: I solved it by removing mysql