# apt-get says Version was not found but it is there

Tags: package-management, repository, vlc

I've added this repository "ppa:videolan/stable-daily" using this command:

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:videolan/stable-daily
```

thin I wrote this command:

```
sudo apt-get update && sudo apt-get install vlc=2.1.2+git20140320+r54512+18+11~ubuntu14.04.1
```

Finally i got this massage:

```
E: Version '2.1.2+git20140320+r54512+18+11~ubuntu14.04.1' for 'vlc' was not found
```

even though I can see it in the repository page. I have Ubuntu 13.10. Is this because of the "ubuntu14.04.1" in the end of the version name, if yes how can I work around it ?

Comment: `sudo apt-get install vlc` should work. buy default apt-get should always install the most recent version available, and the version in the ppa should be most recent (otherwise file a bug with the ppa maintainer).. If vlc is already installed, you may need `sudo apt-get upgrade`.

Comment: I think (correct me if I'm wrong) the statement "ubuntu14.04.1" at the end of the version's name means that it's only for Ubuntu 14.01 and I'm running 13.10 . other non-official repositories provide it for 13.10. So how can I download it from this repository ?

Comment: https://askubuntu.com/a/449/48214 shows how `sudo apt-get install devscripts` and then `rmadison <package name>` will show all available versions, including remote.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want the Latest from this repositoty

https://launchpad.net/~djcj/+archive/vlc-stable

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:djcj/vlc-stable
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: I know, you get 2.1.2 from SC and 2.1.3 is the latest. You want the 2.1.3?

Comment: why can't I get it from the official repo, how come this repo has it but it's not in their official repo ?

Comment: well, there so much stuff that Ubuntu needs to test and check before they go to official repo, i have the same problem with Virtualbox. Its getting better though, versions not to far appart.

Comment: not in ubuntu's repo, in vlc's. this is the officall page: https://launchpad.net/vlc, they provide 2.1.2 for ubuntu 14.01 and 2.0.8 for 13.10

Comment: Yeah, thats because 13.10 is almost at the end of life. July 2014. So whats the point.

Answer (score 5):

First try to see all the available vlc versions on your repositories and PPA's by running the below command,

```
apt-cache policy vlc
```

The output of the above command for mine would be like this,

```
avinash@avinash-Lenovo-IdeaPad-Z500:~$ apt-cache policy vlc:
  Installed: 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1
  Candidate: 2.1.2-1~ppa1
  Version table:
     2.1.2-1~ppa1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/jacob/media/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
     2.0.8+git20140305+r49188+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1 0
        500 http://ppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/ saucy/main amd64 Packages
 *** 2.0.8+git20140211+r49186+13+8~ubuntu13.10.1 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     2.0.8-1 0
        500 http://ubuntu.inode.at/ubuntu/ saucy/universe amd64 Packages
```

The latest version available for vlc on mine is `2.1.2-1~ppa1` which was provided by @jacob's PPA.So i have to run the below command on my terminal to install the latest version of vlc.

```
sudo apt-get install vlc=2.1.2-1~ppa1
```

Comment: You don't need to specify the version number in your case. _Candidate_ is the version which would be installed, so a simple install or upgrade, would pull the newer version in.

Comment: yes that's true, but I'm asking about how can I get this package from a specific repository when they provide it for 14.01 only. I want it from the official repository.

Comment: When they provide a particular package version only for 14.04, then it won't be displayed on yours.because you're running 13.10

Comment: Dobey, that's an example

Comment: other non-official repositories provide it for 13.10. is it the only way to get it ?

Answer (score 2):

No, the version is not there. You are on 13.10 and have added the repository for 13.10, not 14.04. Replace the `14.04.1` in the version string with `13.10.1` to install the package, assuming the recipe is built for 13.10 as well as 14.04.

Comment: I replaced "2.1.2+git20140320+r54512+18+11~ubuntu14.04.1" by "2.1.2+git20140320+r54512+18+11~ubuntu13.10.1" in my command but the same thing. I think because this version (2.1.2) is only available for 14.01 . all the packages that has "ubuntu13.10.1" at the end of their version name are (2.0.8). can I do anything here or should I just download it from another repository.