# What is proper way to get specific version of package

Tags: apt, package-management

I am using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS

I need to use curl package. But it comes in version `7.35.0` with [known SSL bug](http://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1319/) (already fixed in next version)

I either need lower version `<= 7.33.0` or higher `>= 7.36.0` to make it works, but how can I do it?

Do I need to manually install curl? I checked synaptics, ["Force Version" feature](http://cdn.howtogeek.com/wp-content/uploads/2012/07/image21.png) is greyed out. I also checked `apt-cache showpkg curl`, there is no other version available. I also tried to add "proposed" repositories, no new curl version either.

What should I do? I am thinking about getting .deb package from previous ubuntu release...

Comment: You either need to find a ppa with the new version or compile from source.

Comment: To specify a version with apt-get see http://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version

Answer (score 1, accepted):

7.36 is in a ppa

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:costamagnagianfranco/ettercap-stable-backports
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install curl
```

To show all versions available, use the "madison" option for apt-cache

See [How can I see all versions of a package that are available in the archive?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/447/how-can-i-see-all-versions-of-a-package-that-are-available-in-the-archive)

To specify a specific version with apt-get see [How to install specific Ubuntu packages, with exact version?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/92019/how-to-install-specific-ubuntu-packages-with-exact-version)

Comment: thanks, just installed 7.36, but bug is still there =( thanks anyway

Comment: If you have a bug, I highly suggest you file a bug report.

Comment: Today I build newest version 7.37 using sources, bug still exists so indeed I filed [a bug report](https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1376/)