# How to build curl with the latest openssl?

Tags: compiling, curl

So I build openssl

```
./config
make
sudo make install
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl`
```

I build curl

```
./configure --with-ssl 
make
make install
```

OpenSSL looks installed correctly:

```
openssl version
OpenSSL 1.0.1g 7 Apr 2014
```

however curl uses old openssl version (1.0.1f instead of 1.0.1g):

```
curl --version
curl 7.37.0 (x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.37.0 OpenSSL/1.0.1f zlib/1.2.8 libidn/1.28 libssh2/1.4.3 librtmp/2.3
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps ldap ldaps pop3 pop3s rtmp rtsp scp sftp smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IDN IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP
```

how to make curl use new version?

I want to try the newest versions, because I am fighting with some strange openssl/curl bug [#1](https://askubuntu.com/questions/473507/what-is-proper-way-to-get-specific-version-of-package) [#2](https://sourceforge.net/p/curl/bugs/1376/)

Edit: I also tried `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl`, no success

Edit2: So far I also tried:

- `sudo ./configure --with-ssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl`
- `./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`
- `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure`
- `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --with-ssl`
- `PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl`

no success...

Answer (score 15):

You need to specify the directory where OpenSSL is installed (your symlink is neither necessary nor sufficient)

`./configure --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl`

EDIT: Alternatively, you can set your `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` environment variable (as suggested by `./configure --help`):

`PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure`

Comment: first option gives me `configure: error: OpenSSL libs and/or directories were not found where specified!` Please see my edit - there is no error with `--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl/include/openssl` but old openssl is used. second option configures curl without HTTPS

Comment: I may have gotten the directories slightly wrong, I don't have access to a Linux box right now... Basically, your manual OpenSSL installation put a file `openssl.pc`somewhere, you need to point `PKG_CONFIG_PATH` to the directory where that file is (and make sure you have `pkg-config` installed, of course).

Comment: PKG_CONFIG_PATH path is correct, I have pkg-config installed too, but somehow it doesn't work. without `--with-ssl` there is no HTTPS, with `--with-ssl`it throws error `configure: error: OpenSSL libs and/or directories were not found where specified!
`

Comment: Where and how did you install ssl ? Use the correct path.

Comment: @bodhi.zazen I have install both Ubuntu package from official repositories and compiled openssl in `/usr/local/ssl`

Comment: both options suggested by @fkraiem worked fine on Ubuntu 14.04 with older openssl installed via "apt-get" (OpenSSL 1.0.1f 6 Jan 2014) and then manually upgraded OpenSSL up to (OpenSSL 1.0.2k  26 Jan 2017). And "/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig" is the right place for openssl.pc file. Thanks!

Comment: How is it possible for you all to compile curl, especially @DmitryShevkoplyas as recently as a couple months ago?  ./configure tests OpenSSL at path provided by --with-ssl=____ and if HMAC_Update is not found, it abandons ssl.  Well, OpenSSL contains HMAC_Update, but the test fails, and cannot include ssl.  Ubuntu 14.04, OpenSSL 1.0.2l, curl 7.46

Comment: Bravo. That was GREATE!!!

Answer (score 11):

```
sudo apt-get install libssl-dev
./configure --prefix=/usr --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo make
sudo make install
```

Is all I needed to build curl 7.43 on ubuntu 15.04

Comment: Beautiful. This worked on 19.04. Somehow `curl` couldn't detect my `openssl`, so I did these exact steps with `libssl-dev` and it worked like charm!

Answer (score 6):

What I found out, when I was going through the same exercise, is that curl simply can't work with openssl static libraries. It was always searching for dynamic, no matter what I was doing, so eventually I did three things that worked for me

```
Configured openssl with enable-shared: ./config enable-shared
Configured curl with openssl: ./configure --with-ssl
Used LD_LIBRARY_PATH: LD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/lib:/usr/local/ssl/lib /usr/local/bin/curl -V
```

The latter command with -V flag will show the openssl version used by curl. I've added /usr/local/lib to LD_LIBRARY_PATH to make sure that curl uses the right libcurl version.

Comment: This helped me, particularly `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` which I've added to bash_profile. I did something similar, but instead of the first line, I used `export CFLAGS=-fPIC; ./config shared` (not enable-shared). For curl, I used `--with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl` although the path arg may have been redundant.

Comment: I'm glad it worked for you and yes, path in --with-ssl is redundant, because what you've provided is a default location for the build.

Answer (score 5):

This was a long and arduous path for me. Hours and hours (you know how it is). Here's what I found:

For **Ubuntu 12.04 / 14.04** you have to *manually* install both **openssl** and **curl**

#### Manually install openssl 1.0.2g:

```
sudo apt-get install make # (Install compiling library Make)
wget https://www.openssl.org/source/openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz # (Download the latest OpenSSL 1.0.2g binaries)
tar -xzvf openssl-1.0.2g.tar.gz # (Extract the tar ball to the local directory)
cd openssl-1.0.2g # (Enter extracted OpenSSL directory)
sudo ./config # (Configure binaries for compiling)
sudo make install # (install configured binaries)
sudo ln -sf /usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl `which openssl` # (This will create a sym link to the new binaries)
openssl version -v
```

#### *IF YOU WANT NGHTTP2 (optional / recommended):*

```
# Get build requirements
# Some of these are used for the Python bindings
# this package also installs
sudo apt-get install g++ make binutils autoconf automake autotools-dev libtool pkg-config \
  zlib1g-dev libcunit1-dev libssl-dev libxml2-dev libev-dev libevent-dev libjansson-dev \
  libjemalloc-dev cython python3-dev python-setuptools

# Build nghttp2 from source
git clone https://github.com/tatsuhiro-t/nghttp2.git
cd nghttp2
autoreconf -i
automake
autoconf
./configure
make
sudo make install
```

#### Manually install curl:

```
cd ~
sudo apt-get build-dep curl
wget http://curl.haxx.se/download/curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
tar -xvjf curl-7.46.0.tar.bz2
cd curl-7.46.0
./configure --with-nghttp2 --with-ssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl # This is the line I had the most trouble with, especially figure out --with-libssl-prefix
make
sudo make install
sudo ldconfig
```

#### Final Steps

```
sudo ldconfig
sudo service apache2 restart # if you're using apache
```

Now that you're done, try `curl --version` and make sure you see the correct version of openssl in there. Specifically openssl >= 1.0.2g (and nghttp2 if you opted for it)

```
$ curl --version
curl 7.50.2 (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu) libcurl/7.50.2 OpenSSL/1.0.2k zlib/1.2.8 nghttp2/1.21.0-DEV
Protocols: dict file ftp ftps gopher http https imap imaps pop3 pop3s rtsp smb smbs smtp smtps telnet tftp 
Features: IPv6 Largefile NTLM NTLM_WB SSL libz TLS-SRP HTTP2 UnixSockets
```

citations: [curl](https://gist.github.com/fideloper/f72997d2e2c9fbe66459) [opennssl](http://www.miguelvallejo.com/updating-to-openssl-1-0-2g-on-ubuntu-server-12-04-14-04-lts-to-stop-cve-2016-0800-drown-attack/)

Answer (score 3):

```
./configure --with-ssl=/usr/lib/ssl --libdir=/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu
sudo make
sudo make install
```

After struggling some hours I managed to enable https with libcurl 7.38 in ubuntu 15.05

Answer (score 2):

I managed to compile curl using static OpenSSL libraries. This is the tl;dr version:

**OpenSSL**

```
./config no-shared --prefix=$PWD/_installdir
make depend && make && make install
```

**curl**

```
LIBS="-ldl" ./configure --prefix=$PWD/_installdir --with-ssl=/something/opensslrootdir/_installdir --disable-shared
make && make install
```

The `LIBS="-ldl"` part is essential.

Answer (score 0):

Compiling openssl use default configure **generates static library only**, so, if you want to use static library in curl, you can do like this:

```
LIBS="-ldl -lpthread" ./configure --disable-shared --prefix=/usr/local/curl --with-ssl=/usr/local/ssl
```

I sought the answer from [here](https://github.com/curl/curl/issues/567).

***NOTE: following this way only generates curl static library.***

Answer (score 0):

I generally followed Jacksonkr's answer, but I needed all of the above mentioned by others together:

```
LIBS="-ldl" PKG_CONFIG_PATH=/usr/local/ssl/lib/pkgconfig ./configure --with-ssl --with-libssl-prefix=/usr/local/ssl --disable-shared
```

`--disable-shared` is optional, I guess, it;s just I need it

Answer (score 0):

I was able to mitigate this issue by adding the `--without-zlib` option.