# Unable to downgrade firefox version using apt-get in Ubuntu

Tags: apt, firefox, selenium

**Note:** This is not duplicate of [How do I downgrade Firefox v. 57 to v. 56?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/977138/how-do-i-downgrade-firefox-v-57-to-v-56).

I have installed firefox using `sudo apt-get install firefox` 
Right now it is installing version 63.0 which has some issue with selenium webDriver.

So I want to downgrade because this selenium webDriver is working fine with version 57.0.4.

I tried `sudo apt-get install firefox=57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1` which is not working and saying that:

> E: Version '57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1' for 'firefox' was not found

The strange thing is that I am able to install version 45 using `sudo apt install firefox=45.0.2+build1-0ubuntu1`

I have taken the syntax from [Here](https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/firefox).

Any help will be highly appreciated!

Comment: Thank you for your prompt response. You mean I need to download the *.deb package locally?

Comment: To see all the versions available run `apt-cache madison firefox` or see https://askubuntu.com/questions/447/how-can-i-see-all-versions-of-a-package-that-are-available-in-the-archive  If it is not listed you will have to manually go find the version you want and download and install it or find a supported repo or PPA containing it.  Going along with the comment above that version is found at https://launchpad.net/ubuntu/xenial/+source/firefox

Answer (score 0):

You could just remove your current firefox's version and install deb package: `sudo apt remove firefox && wget http://launchpadlibrarian.net/352570250/firefox_57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb && sudo dpkg -i firefox_57.0.4+build1-0ubuntu0.16.04.1_amd64.deb`

Comment: I know this approach and its working for me. Even though it will be good if i can do this using `apt-get`. It can solve dependency issues if i have in future :)

Comment: 16.04 and newer releases of Ubuntu can optionally replace `dpkg -i` with `apt install` for dependency resolution.

Answer (score 0):

You should read Debian Wiki.
The Key for future similar to gentoo is the file  /etc/apt/preferences (similar to mask)

https://wiki.debian.org/RollbackUpdate